# Tkinter entry.get adding a line after the value for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So this is my code:

```
name = entry0.get()
name = str(name)
print(f"pls give {name} all")
```

and for some reason this is the output: (assuming the name was Dany)
"pls give Dany"
"all"
whatever text comes after the `name` that's from `entry0` gets printed in another line and if sent in an application, another message.

Why?

Comment: This isn't enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the rest of context its hard to deduce what the root issue is. I'm going to assume your output looks like:

```
pls give Dany
all
```

If this is the case, it's because the `name` variable has a new line character ('\n') appended at the end of it. You can use the python [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method to remove the new line before its printed.

```py
print(f"pls give {name.strip()} all")
```